# Simple confirmation popup dialog box

Tags: forms

How is it possible to create simple confirmation popup dialog boxes in Drupal 7?

I've searched a lot, but I found tons of non-working suggestions and code.

Comment: If you found solutions that do not work (for you, or not at all) please tell us which solutions you tried out, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Also give us a little more description of what the confirmation is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it!!!

Here's a simple 100% functioning exmple:

```
$form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Delete'),
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'if(!confirm("Really Delete?")){return false;}'),
);
```

I hope this helps.

Happy coding :)

Comment: you should accept this if it solved your problem (click the check mark below the vote count)

Comment: @Chaulky I want to check it, but a popup box showed up telling me that i can accept it tomorrow but not today! Don't worry, i check it tomorrow :)

Comment: You'd be better off setting a class in attributes and then picking up that class in a javascript Drupal.behaviors wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has a native [confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/7) function, but it is server side rather than Javascript based, which is what I assume you mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox module which enables this type of functionality to be built relatively easily:
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/cmcintosh/2644004