# Display delete confirmations in a modal window

Tags: javascript, entities

How do I display delete confirmation form in a modal window? I have a view which displays submissions of an entity form. Each one has a 'delete' link for the admin to remove a particular submission, but clicking it goes to a new delete confirmation page (`entityform/[nid]/delete`). How can I display this confirmation page in a modal overlay, like the edit forms?

I tried the overlay_path module but it tried to display a styled page in the overlay and it looked terrible with my current theme

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/simple-confirmation-popup-dialog-box

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal and then use menu_alter to use following code and see if it helps.

```
function modulename_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['entityform/%entityform/delete']['modal'] = TRUE;
}
```

Be sure to clear cache.

Comment: That did open the page in a modal, but it tried to use the page styles in it and it looked messed up. Also it looks like it used its own modal style rather than the usual Drupal overlay. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Module **Modal operaitons** do this. https://www.drupal.org/project/modal It is no readme, but here is example. This link was open node view in modal window.

```
//As Example:
<a href="/modal/node/NID/nojs" class="ctools-use-modal">View</a>
```

Or this my code for delete node (for **Views PHP**)

```
<a href="<?php global $base_url; echo $base_url; ?>/modal/node/<?php echo $row->nid; ?>/delete/nojs" class="ctools-use-modal">Delete</a>
```